# Primitive of $\left(x +\sqrt{1 + x^2}\right)^n$

Tags: integration

> How to find a primitive of $\left(x +\sqrt{1 + x^2}\right)^n$?

I have started it by parts but it never could end in a good position.

Comment: Maybe a trigonometric/hyperbolic substitution could be used?

Comment: @Khallil Benyattou: Can you tell what, sir?

Comment: Had you tried a change of the kind $x+\sqrt{1+x^2}=u$? (Im not sure any way if this can work).

Comment: Haven't actually tried it, but that's what the $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ screamed out if integration by parts didn't work. I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 6):

$\sqrt{1+x^2}$ looks like a trig transformation, but with the "wrong" sign. So we try with hyperbolic substitution:

$$x=\sinh t$$
$$dx = \cosh t \,dt$$

$$\int (\sinh t + \cosh t)^n \cosh t\,dt$$
$$=\int (e^t)^n (e^t + e^{-t})/2\, dt=\frac12 \int e^{t(n+1)}+e^{t(n-1)}\,dt$$
$$=\frac12\left(\frac{e^{t(n+1)}}{n+1}+\frac{e^{t(n-1)}}{n-1}\right)$$

Now you just need $e^t = \sinh t + \cosh t = x+\sqrt{1+x^2}$ to get back to $x$.

Answer (score 4):

> $$\int(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})^ndx$$

Use Euler substitution $\color{gray}{x=\frac{u^2-1}{2u},\;dx=\bigg(1-\frac{u^2-1}{2u^2}\bigg)}$

$$\int\frac{1}{2}(u^2+1)u^{n-2}du$$

Expanding the integrand $\color{gray}{(u^2+1)u^{n-2}}$ gives $\color{gray}{u^{n-2}+u^n}$

$$\frac{1}{2}\int(u^{n-2}+u^n)du$$

$$=\frac{u^{n-1}}{2(n-1)}+\frac{u^{n+1}}{2(n+1)}+C$$

$$\boxed{\color{red}{\frac{\bigg(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\bigg)^n\bigg(n\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\bigg)}{n^2-1}+C}}$$

Comment: Can you tell me more about Euler substitution? I'm new to this term.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution

Comment: You have a typo on the penultimate step

Comment: I will fix it right now

Answer (score 1):

Try substituting $u=\sinh^{-1}x$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @HowDoMarh.This is only intended as a hint as to how to proceed

Comment: But with no indication about the reason why one could select this substitution, the utility of the answer is zero.

Comment: @Did: it becomes obvious as soon as you try it. In any event the same method has already been demonstrated by Orion

Comment: Actually there are *methods* to choose these changes of variable, and to be sure before hand which ones will work. These methods are the interesting part, not to be given their result.

Answer (score 0):

start with $x=\tan u$:

\begin{align}
\int (x+\sqrt{+x^2})^ndx&=\int (\sec u + \tan u)^n\sec^2u du\\
\end{align}

Now using integration by parts with $dz=(\sec u + \tan u)^n\sec u du$ and $v=\sec u$ we obtain
\begin{align}
I&=\int (\sec u + \tan u)^n\sec u \sec u du\\
&=\frac 1n \sec u (\sec u + \tan u)^n-\frac 1n \int(\sec u+\tan u)^n \sec u \tan u du
\end{align}
again we choose $dz$ as before and $v=\tan u$ to obtain

\begin{align}
I&=\frac 1n \sec u (\sec u + \tan u)^n-\frac {1}{n^2}(\sec u+\tan u)^n \tan u +\frac{1}{n^2}I
\end{align}
Therefore $$I=\frac{(n \sec u-\tan (u)) (\tan (u)+\sec (u))^n}{n^2-1}+C$$ substituting back to $x$ we obtain $$I=\frac{(n \sqrt{1+x^2}-x) (x+\sqrt{1+x^2})^n}{n^2-1}+C$$